# Asset isn't Precompiled in Production Environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, slim-lang

I'm trying to add page specific CSS to my rails app. On the review_quote view, I want the review_quote.css to be rendered.

As of right now, the syntax I have works for the dev environment, because (I think) the asset pipeline isn't compressed into one file.

How do I get view specific CSS on my production environment?

This might also be relevant:

```
# production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Using .slim instead of .erb

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Quotes#show

Showing /app/app/views/quotes/review_quote.html.slim where line #2 raised:

review_quote.css isn't precompiled
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: - content_for :head do 
2:   = stylesheet_link_tag "review_quote", media: "all"
3: 
4: 
5: #review-quote
```

Comment: Did you try this? Set `config.serve_static_assets` to false and in `config/environments/production.rb`, add the asset to the precompilation array: `config.assets.precompile += %w[review_quote.css]`

Comment: I can't set `serve_static_assets` to false since it would mess with other aspects of my app (just took it over from a previous dev). Adding it to the precompile list compiled it, but into the `application.css` meaning it was served throughout the app and not just on this view.